# How to compile Logic.v in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm using Coq 8.4pl6, and want to compile Logic.v (of Coq standard library) in Coq and to see its output as an example of module compiling and printing, but failed.

More specifically, `tauto` at line 107 of Logic.v was failed:

```
   104  Theorem and_cancel_l : forall A B C : Prop,
   105    (B -> A) -> (C -> A) -> ((A /\ B <-> A /\ C) <-> (B <-> C)).
   106  Proof.
   107    intros; tauto.
   108  Qed.
```

The process I tried is as follows:

1. I tried `coqc Logic.v` from console, which produces `Error: tauto failed` in line 107. I thought this is because Coq initial environment already imported `Logic.vo`, so loading the same module twice made the error.
2. Next, I tried to compile with the empty initial state by running `coqc -nois Logic.v`, which produces the following error. I didn't understand the meaning of this error...

   ```
   File ".../Logic.v", line 107, characters 10-15:
   Anomaly: Incorrect tactic expression. Received exception is: 
   Anomaly: Uncaught exception Nametab.GlobalizationError(_). Please report.. 
   Please report.
   ```

Is there any way to compile `Logic.v` without errors?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with compiling [Logic.v](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.4pl6/theories/Init/Logic.v) seems to be due to the fact that it redefines the inductive types `True, False, and, or, ex, ex2, eq` and the constants `not, iff, IF_then_else, all, eq_ind_r, eq_rec_r, eq_rect_r, subrelation, unique, uniqueness`.

The automated tactics must consider (and treat) these "new" types and constant different from the ones that were loaded first, when Coq starts up.

Once these `Definition` and `Inductive`  statements were removed from Logic.v, I was able to compile the file.

Hope this helps.  (A more complete answer would explain exactly where in the startup process this happens.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess you tried that without -nois option (= Coq default settings). I (partly) understand the cause of compile error. Next I try how to compile with -nois option with studying Coq startup process.